# SSH into multiple servers based on Domain HOST ACL

Tags: ssh, haproxy, access-control-list

What I’m trying to achieve here is using 1 Entry point for all of my servers using a private network.
1 server with Public IP access and then pointed multiple domains on it, after that use ACL to decide which backend to use.

**Example Configurations:**

```
frontend UK-1
bind *:77
option tcplog
mode tcp

tcp-request inspect-delay 60s
acl is_ssh payload(0,7) -m bin 5353482d322e30 # "SSH-2.0" in hex
tcp-request content accept if is_ssh

# Define hosts
acl l1_dom req.ssl_sni -i uk-ep-1.example.com
use_backend l1_ssh if l1_dom

acl i1_dom req.ssl_sni -i -i uk-ep-1.i1.example.com
use_backend i1_ssh if i1_dom

backend DefaultBackend
mode http
http-request deny deny_status 403

backend i1_ssh
mode tcp
timeout connect 3000
timeout server  7200000
option          httpchk
server          ssh 192.168.0.155:2905

backend l1_ssh
mode tcp
timeout connect 3000
timeout server  7200000
option          httpchk
server          ssh 192.168.0.167:2917
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working!

Answer (score 0):

SSH doesn't support SNI, which is why this isn't working. There have been discussions in the past to implement this, see [this](https://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2013-June/031435.html) or [this](https://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2013-November/031805.html) thread for example, but so far, that's not done.